# DataGridView size is out of splitContainer panel even the Dock property is Fill

Tags: c#, datagridview, dock, splitcontainer

There are a SplitContainer and couple of DataViewGrids. In Designer I docked DataViewGrids to Panel1 and Panel2 of SplitContainer respectively. So, in designer everithing seems to be OK. But when I start the program, the DataGridView seems like it's docked to the main form, because the size of the Grid is the main Form size. I use the Grids with bindings to DataSet. When I try to use not binded blanc Grids, everithing is ok. The grids size matches the splitContainer Panels sizes. That drives me insane:(

Answer (score 2):

ok you should set dockstyle of grid to fill the panel
as this

```
datagrid1.Dock=DockStyle.Fill;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Put those expressions in the Form_Load, doesn't work. The dataGridViews has properties Dock and both of them are Fill.

Answer (score 2):

So I resolved, that problem. I put that code after all data bindings of dataGRidView

```
dataGridViewPO.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
dataGridViewPO.Parent = splitContainer1.Panel1;
```